# Problem in indefinite integral. (Exponential)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm given this integral to integrate. I've no idea where to start with. Perhaps someone can give me some hints or guide me. Thanks a lot.

$$\int\frac{(x^3)e^{x^2}{}}{x^2+1}dx$$

Comment: Try the substitution $u = 1 + x^2$ ?

Comment: I've tried. But couldn't solve it.

Comment: I see. There is no expression for this indefinite integral in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: How if it's in non-elementary functions? How to solve it? I'm new to this type of question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mathxx If a solution is not represented by elementary functions alone, one can pursue a series solution.  I have provided terms to order $10$ for this integral.  Let me know other  ways I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @Dr.MV. You're the best person to learn with. I really appreciate your solution.

Comment: @mathxx That means a lot to me.  It is my pleasure to help however I can.

Comment: @Dr.MV Can I know how to apply the big O notation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=1+x^2$.  Then, $du=2xdx$, and $x^2=u-1$.  Thus, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^3e^{x^{2}}}{1+x^2}dx&=\int \frac{x^2e^{x^{2}}}{1+x^2}xdx\\\\
&=\frac12 \int \frac{(u-1)e^{u-1}}{u}du\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2e}\left(e^u-\int \frac{e^u}{u}du\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2e}\left(e^u-Ei(u)\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2e}\left(e^{1+x^2}-Ei(1+x^2)\right)+C_1
\end{align}$$

We can expand this result in a Taylor series, say about $u=1$ (i.e., $x=0$). We proceed to write the first four derivatives of $Ei(u)$ as

$$\begin{align}
Ei^{1}(u) &= \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)e^u\\
Ei^{2}(u)&=\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{u^2}\right)e^u\\
Ei^{3}(u)&=\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{2}{u^2}+\frac{2}{u^3}\right)e^u\\
Ei^{4}(u)&=\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{3}{u^2}+\frac{6}{u^3} -\frac{6}{u^4}\right)e^u\\
\end{align}$$

whereupon evaluating at $u=1$ gives

$$\begin{align}
Ei(u)&=Ei(1)+e\left((u-1)+\frac16 (u-1)^3-\frac{1}{12}(u-1)^4\right)+O(u^5)\\\\
&=Ei(1)+e\left(x^2+\frac16 x^6-\frac{1}{12}x^8\right)+O(x^{10})
\end{align}$$

Recalling that the series for $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^3e^{x^{2}}}{1+x^2}dx&=\frac{1}{2e}\left(e^{1+x^2}-Ei(1+x^2)\right)+C_1\\\\
&=\frac{1}{4} \left(x^4-\frac{1}{12} x^8\right)+O(x^{10})+C_2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\int\frac{x^{3}e^{x^{2}}}{x^{2}+1}dx=\int\left(xe^{x^{2}}-\frac{xe^{x^{2}}}{x^{2}+1}\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}e^{x^{2}}-\frac{\textrm{Ei}\left(x^{2}+1\right)}{2e}+C
 $$ where $\textrm{Ei}\left(x^{2}+1\right)
 $ is the exponential integral. Maybe it's useful to remaind that $$\frac{d}{dx}\textrm{Ei}\left(x\right)=\frac{e^{x}}{x}.
 $$